# Angular lazy loaded modules getting separate instances of service from shared library

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the following scenario:

- RefreshService: this service needs to be a global singleton shared between lazily loaded feature modules.
- LazyModuleA
- LazyModuleB
- AppModule: the base module that is loaded prior to the lazy modules
- SharedModule: a library that includes the RefreshService, and is packaged into a .tgz file

I'd like LazyModuleA and LazyModuleB to receive the same instance of RefreshService. Instead, when I add console log statements to the constructor I can see that there are 2 separate instances being constructed lazily, when the lazy modules load.

I was under the impression the following solution should work, but I am still seeing the duplicate instances:

```
Injectable({ providedIn: 'root'})
export class RefreshService
```

Refresh service in providers array returned from static forRoot method in SharedModule

```
export class SharedModule {
    static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders<SharedModule> {
        return {
            ngModule: SharedModule,
            providers: [ RefreshService ]
        };
        }
```

Import from tgz package to LazyModuleA and LazyModuleB

```
import { RefreshService } from 'shared-module';
...
// inject in constructor
```

In the base app module, call the forRoot method in the import

```
import { SharedModule } from 'shared-module';
...
imports: [
...
SharedModule.forRoot()
]
```

Has anyone had any luck with this scenario?

Comment: Why do you need the providers ?

Comment: Are you referring to the providers array returned in the ModuleWithProviders from forRoot? I thought the purpose of the forRoot pattern was to ensure that only the base/app module imports the SharedModule with a providers array

Answer (score 0):

It's due to the fact you are using a lazy loaded module that the services are getting their own instances created!. It is provided in the angular documentation itself!

[limiting-provider-scope-by-lazy-loading-modules](https://angular.io/guide/providers#limiting-provider-scope-by-lazy-loading-modules)

> Any component created within a lazy loaded module's context, such as
> by router navigation, gets its own local instance of child provided
> services, not the instance in the root application injector.
> Components in external modules continue to receive the instances
> created for the application root injector.
>
> Though you can provide services by lazy loading modules, not all
> services can be lazy loaded. For instance, some modules only work in
> the root module, such as the Router. The Router works with the global
> location object in the browser.

Comment: But what would I do differently to ensure that the lazy loaded modules receive a singleton rather than new instances of the service?